# How to edit my question or is it too localized?

Tags: discussion

I have a [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207006/sql-server-compressed-full-backup-with-2gb-size-and-different-file-extention-is?noredirect=1#comment404439_207006)  which was marked as too localized. I understand that it looks very specific and I have workaround, but it is unclear the reason why that happens and also someone else can have the same issue.

The question is now deleted and invisible to users with less than 10K rep but this is a screenshot

[image]

In my point of view the strength of such community is to help with more specific question for which there is no info in the internet.

Please correct me what in my point is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question has now disappered, so quite hard to follow things now... It should probably have been put here as text. StackExchange is quite vocal about not abusing outside links, but even inside ones can disappear...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I added a screenshot of the deleted question

Comment: Sorry - I deleted it. 10x @TomV to add screenshot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, a couple of things:

- This doesn't really seem to be database-related. Your FTP program either isn't copying the file in binary mode or something else is happening to the file somewhere along the way because of the file extension. Your peers can't troubleshoot this because none of us has this same combination of insisting on using `.full`, transferring the files with FileZilla with whatever settings you have, over whatever network and firewall you have (you could have intrusion detection software, on-the-fly encryption, or other things that "touch" files on their way through, and maybe `.bak` files are in the exception list - we just can't possibly know any of this).
- "Too localized" in my eyes is when you are trying to find a solution to a problem that nobody else will have, or who won't accept obvious workarounds. You are insisting on using `.full` which appears to be broken for that reason alone. Most reasonable people would just stop doing that and use an extension that works.

You'll need to solve your FileZilla or whatever problem separately from anything we could help you with here. This is not a database problem and not enough of your peers would benefit from this to make it a database problem.

Comment: Thanks to replay @AaronBertrand. Now, I understand the point of the mark.